# how can i access my kibana dashboard ?? how do i know my deployment is correct or not?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, kibana

I have Kubernetes cluster and deployed kibana using Nginx as ingress controller. Could anyone tell me how to can I access kibana dashboard and how do I know that my deployment is right ??

Answer (score 3):

The default kibana port is 5601. You may open kibana by opening `localhost:5601` or `IP_ADDRESS:5601` or `http://YOURDOMAIN.com:5601` in your browser. Ypu may find more details here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/access.html

Comment: ip ?? ip of which node. where from I get domain ??